# How to disable 'renaming' a file in java?

Tags: java

Is there any way in java by which we can disable renaming a specific file( for eg. MS-Excel file)just as we can hide it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disabling renaming of files would be something that the operating system/file system would have to enforce. It's not something that a Java application would have the honor/privilege of doing.

Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "just as we can hide it". Currently, Java can *NOT* hide a file (see: [bug# 4267530](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4267530)).

Comment: Yes it does. I'm using 1.5 in that it supports Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
where cmd is String cmd[]={"attrib","+h",filename}

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by setting access rights to a file (ex. `chmod` under unix), but only using OS commands, executing it with `Runtime.exec()`